# Discord.js slash command register code not working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I‘m working on a discord bot with node.js and I wanted to register slash commands. Now, when i run in the shell, the following error gets throwed:[image: Invalid Form Body Error]
What should I do to correct it?
Here is where I got the code from: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#command-registration.
And this is the code:

```js
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(JSON.stringify(command.data));
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: I would write the error as code, but the console doesn‘t let its content copied. I‘m sorry when the image is not available. Then please contact me

Answer (score -1):

The only logic derivation that I find from my code is in line 12

```
commands.push(command.data.toJSON())
```

This is also the way discord.js guide suggests it: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#guild-commands

Comment: Yea at the beginning I used that but it gave an undefined error